# loop through NSDictionary to create NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have the following NSDictionary data:

```
{
    "ADDED_DATE" = "2011-02-04 00:56:44.732014";
    "ADDED_LOGON" = ABCD;
    "AGENT_BROKER_IND" = N;
    "ALLOCATION_IND" = AUTOPROP;
    "BILLPRINT_DLVY_IND" = PAPER;
    "BILLPRINT_LOCATION_NAME" = "COMPANY ABC";
    "BILLPRINT_LVL_CIM" = 05852015;
    "BILL_DUE_DT" = "2011-02-01";
    "BILL_LOGO_CD" = XXLOGO;
    "BILL_PERIOD_MONTH" = 02;
    "BILL_PER_BEG_DT" = "2011-02-01";
    "BILL_PER_END_DT" = "2011-02-28";
    "BILL_RUN_DT" = "2011-02-03";
    "BILL_TOTAL_PREMIUM" = "342.84";
    IDX = ".000339709222474931";
    "LIST_BILL_CASE_NUM" = 0318T4;
    "LIST_BILL_CIM" = 05852019;
    "OWNING_CARRIER" = WX;
    "PAST_DUE_DT" = "2011-03-04";
    "REMIT_CYCLE" = MONTHLY;
    "RUN_NUMBER" = 1;
    "TOTAL_ADJUSTMENTS" = "0.00";
    "TOTAL_AMOUNT_DUE" = "685.68";
    "TOTAL_CURRENT_CHARGES" = "342.84";
    "TOTAL_PASTDUE_AMOUNT" = "342.84";
},
    {
    "ADDED_DATE" = "2010-12-04 08:20:45.292516";
    "AGENT_BROKER_IND" = N;
    "ALLOCATION_IND" = AUTOPROP;
    "BILLPRINT_DLVY_IND" = WEBPORTAL;
    "BILLPRINT_LOCATION_NAME" = "ANCHOR ABC";
    "BILLPRINT_LVL_CIM" = 05721991;
    "BILL_DUE_DT" = "2010-12-15";
    "BILL_FORM_TYPE_CD" = FE4;
    "BILL_LOGO_CD" = XXLOGO;
    "BILL_PERIOD_MONTH" = 01;
    "BILL_PER_BEG_DT" = "2011-01-01";
    "BILL_PER_END_DT" = "2011-01-31";
    "BILL_RUN_DT" = "2010-12-03";
    "BILL_TOTAL_PREMIUM" = "277.96";
    IDX = ".000389371998789428";
    "LIST_BILL_CASE_NUM" = 9858Q8;
    "LIST_BILL_CIM" = 05721991;
    "OWNING_CARRIER" = FE;
    "PAST_DUE_DT" = "2010-12-31";
    "REMIT_CYCLE" = MONTHLY;
    "RUN_NUMBER" = 1;
    "TOTAL_ADJUSTMENTS" = "0.00";
    "TOTAL_AMOUNT_DUE" = "277.96";
    "TOTAL_CURRENT_CHARGES" = "277.96";
    "TOTAL_PASTDUE_AMOUNT" = "0.00";
},
```

And I am trying to figure out how convert this data into arrays.  With this example I need to have it broken down into 2 arrays with those arrays filled with it's data (hope that made sense).

I can loop through the data like this:

```
NSString *key;

for (key in finalDict) {
    NSLog(@"%@", key);
}
```

And I get each "array" of data in "key" ... but how to I break it down from there into it's own arrays?  Sorry if I'm confusing.  =)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish. Also, if you want individual arrays, do you want an array of arrays or each array on its own?

Comment: I'm trying to take that data ... and use it in a UITableView.  Each "array" of data would be it's own row.

Comment: I would assume it would be best to have an array of arrays, but I'm pretty new at this (but learning fast) so which ever would be best to use on a UITableView.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: So would each entry in your dictionary be one TableView cell? In other words, each cell would contain one "ADDED_DATE", "AGENT_BROKER_IND", etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks to me like you have an NSArray of NSDictionaries, judging by your code. If you actually want to load all the data into a UITableView I would suggest that in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you create an NSDictionary and load it with the current indexes NSDictionary like this:

```
NSDictionary *currentDictionary = [self.myArrayOfDictionaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //now do some stuff with your dictionary
    cell.addedDate.text = [currentDictionary objectForKey:@"ADDED_DATE"];
    cell.agentBrokerInd.text = [currentDictionary objectForKey:@"AGENT_BROKER_IND"];
    ///etc.....
```

Of course, it depends on how you set up your UITableViewCell and whether or not you want to have outlets for each attribute or not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make `key` an `NSArray` type instead of `NSString`. Then you can access the array's elements, adding them to another array or whatever else you want to do. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) is the `NSArray` documentation.

Comment: Ah ... thank you.  Not sure why I didn't think of that.  Now to figure out how to get this fitted into the correct arrays.